# Inserir API KEY da aws (amazon)

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-aws, android-manifest

Gostaria de saber onde insiro a API KEY da Amazon, no meu projeto do android.
Utilizarei um banco de dados instalado na Amazon, para gravar e buscar meus dados.

Segue meu gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
}
```

Meu Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="projeto.projeto_desafio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) to determine the device's location to within a very small area. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Allows the API to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:
Vou utilizar a base de dados na nuvem. Desculpe mas realmente sou por fora da Amazon. Vou utilizar o serviço de banco de dados. Só o que tenho eh a API key e o formato do json que devo enviar.

Comment: O que você esta querendo fazer? Qual serviço da AWS você quer utiliziar?

Comment: Banco na nuvem. Desculpe mas realmente sou por fora da Amazon. Vou utilizar o serviço de banco de dados. Só o que tenho eh a API key e o formato do json que devo enviar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henrique, tudo bem ? Cara, a AWS não recomenda trabalhar com API_KEY e API_SECRET_KEY dentro da aplicação. Eles utilizam uma coisa chamada *Identity Provider*. O que isso significa ? É que você pode usar provedores de identidade, como o Google, Facebook, Twitter entre outros. 
Imagine que no seu app você implemente social login com esses caras, e para implementar social login com esses caras você teve que entrar em cada console de desenvolvimento deles ([Google](https://console.developers.google.com/), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/) e [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/)) e registar seu aplicativo.Nesse registro você recebeu um ID, lá na AWS você coloca esses IDs dizendo que esses são seus provedores de identidade, e que quando o usuário estiver logado ele pode ter acesso a N recursos determinados por você. Abaixo segue alguns links que podem te ajudar.

- Mobile Hub: Ele já cria um app de exemplo baseado na sua necessidade
  [Mobile Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/mobile/)
- AWS Cognito: Serviço que provê autenticação de usuários
  [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/cognito/)
- Exeplos de uso do DynamoDB
  [AWS Blog Example](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1U4RV2QI1MVWS/Amazon-DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-1-Loading-Data)
  [DynamoDB doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html)
- Exemplos de uso de serviços da AWS
  [Amazon AWS SDK Samples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples)
  [AWS Labs](https://github.com/awslabs)

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Magina @HenriqueMendes, tamo junto!